# Would this thinking about the dot product hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, vectors

Background today I completed the chapter on the dot product of vectors. But in trying to figure out exactly what the dot product is.

I came to the conclusion that it can be interpreted as the length of the adjacent side of the right triangle formed from a triangle with a hypotenuse of length of the product of the lengths of the 2 vectors.

Or am I way of the mark?

Comment: Not sure about your formulation. You may want to check against [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). They have illustrations to show what they mean.

Comment: Check out the figure in that Wikipedia page labelled 'scalar projection' in particular.

Comment: It sounds right to me. For nonzero $a$ and $b$, we have $\cos(\theta) = (a\cdot b)/(|a||b|)$. Comparing this with $\cos(\theta) = \text{adjacent}/\text{hypotenuse}$ shows that your observation is valid.

Comment: Never thought of checking wiki :( what I am trying to do is just find an explanation for myself to relate it to

Comment: While it may be correct if properly formulated, it is not recommended. One should think of dot product as a way to measure length and angle in a vector space.

Comment: @ Quang I understand what you are saying but, however when I learn I like to relate it to something I am familiar with, by example when I differentiate I am looking for the slope of the tangent not merely performing calculations

Comment: Exactly, but in this case, it is not natural to turn a product of length (area) to a length. Also, since it is possible (and easier) to define different dot products on a vector space, the angle between two vectors come as a consequence of the dot product.

Comment: @ Quang when I get there what you say will probably make perfect sense thank you for your comments I really appreciate it, it make me want to learn more

Comment: The interpretation of the dot product is more meaningful when not viewed in purely mathematical terms, but rather by looking at its applications (especially in Physics). See http://mathuprising.comlu.com/dot-product-work-force-distance.html for an example of what I mean.